# Module appearing as uninstalled even though it installed

Tags: python, pip

The title says it all basically. I was trying to code a macro to automate responding to emails, set up the main.py. Just wrote the import and a print. Ran and boom.
Here is a screenshot because I cant actually explain it correctly https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq2Cr.jpg

Comment: Could you add an image of the result of `pip list` This will allow you to check if it actually installed properly.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please describe your environment. What versions of Python are installed on your machine? What version of Python are you running when executing your script? How are you running your script, in a terminal, or via a "run" button in your IDE?

Comment: @ddejohn From the image, I am deducing that he is running python 3.9 (`c:/python39`) and he is running from the terminal.

Comment: @TalinTheDev it shows like the module its installed

Comment: @ddejohn Python version 3.9 installed, v3.9 running, running it through the normal windows console

Comment: I bet you have two different Python installations. To get around that, try `py -m pip`. (I think that'll work -- I haven't used `py` very much.) For example, to install in the right environment, do `py -m pip install pyautogui`.

Comment: @TalinTheDev that cannot be deduced from the information in the screenshot. It is clear that `pyautogui` was installed using Python 3.9, but there is nothing to suggest that Python 3.9 is what is running when OP runs their script using the `py` command in their terminal.

Comment: Please run `py --version` and provide the output.

Comment: @ddejohn : v3.10.2

Comment: @wjandrea I think so, let me check it real quick, ill be right back

Comment: You are installing a package with Python 3.9, but trying to run a script which depends on that package using Python 3.10.

Comment: Yep, it says I have installed py 3.10.2 but it wasnt installated correctly and I forgot to change the PATH, Ill try fixing it changing it as soon as posible then Ill ty updating

Comment: @ddejohn Good point. Thanks, I'll keep notice of that from now on!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer: I tried updating to a new version of python but it seems like it didn't
install correctly, so I opened the installer, uninstalled the new python version from there and now everything works correctly. Thanks to everyone that collaborated!

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of deleting one version of python and keeping the other(as mentioned in the other answer) you can keep both.**

For example if I have `python 3.9` and `python 3.10` I can use environment variables to tell my system which interpreter I want to use.

## For windows

There are two ways to do this on windows computers(one way might work on your computer, the other may not).

**First Way**

To set two interpreters on windows you can search up "control panel" in your windows search bar. Then go to "system and security". On the top right corner their will be a search bar in it type "advanced system settings" till you get something like this:

[image]

Click on "advanced system settings". You will get something like this:

[image]

Then click on the environment variables button. It will lead you to a popup that will look like this:

[image]

Under user variables, click on the "Path" environment variables. Then press the "Edit" button. This will take you to a place where you can add multiple interpreters. You should know the location of your `python.exe` file to proceed. If you don't know the location I recommend going to the [main python website](https://www.python.org/) and going to the setup wizard to see the directory it is installed in then you can trash(delete) that setup wizard.

Now that you know the location to all your interpreters you can one be one click on  "New" and add the directories of all your python interpreters(Note: Don't add the `python.exe` at the end ONLY the directories). Once that is done you can press on "Move Up or Move Down". What this will do is the one that is at the top will be your python interpreter and you can always move it down if you need to use another interpreter(Note: You will only see the results after killing your command prompt and restarting it again. Type `python` in your command prompt and you can see your python version that you specified in your environment variables).

**Second Way**

Watch the snippet of [this video](https://youtu.be/OdIHeg4jj2c?t=185) to learn the second way you can do it on windows.

## Mac/Linux

I am not a geek in Linux(In fact I haven't even owned a Mac or Linux in my life). So, my advice would be to just read what I did In Widows way one and just change the         environment variables that you would do for Mac/Linux and there would probably be a way to specify which one is the main or most important directory. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUIE7CPANfo) to do what I did in windows.(Feel free to edit this section to add the Mac/Linux way).

> **Mac Helpful resources:
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUIE7CPANfo**

## **Back to the Main question!**

Now you can just install the package that you want on the python version that you want!